# While running the code in springboot using dependency "spring-boot-starter-web" I encountered a problem with this:- Unable to close ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

When i am using the "spring-boot-starter-web"dependency it is showing error and when i removed the dependency it working well but i want this dependency on my project for adding security while logging.

While running the code in springboot using dependency "spring-boot-starter-web" I encountered a problem with this:- Unable to close ApplicationContext

```
2023-08-31T20:43:06.073+05:30  WARN 11892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4b1210ee]
   
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740) ~[na:na]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1632) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:559) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:658) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1276) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
   
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:863) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
   
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:851) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
   
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
   
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
   
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
   
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3434) ~[na:na]
   
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2536) ~[na:na]
   
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
   
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
   
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
   
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]... 28 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, dependency conflicts can lead to issues during ApplicationContext shutdown. Ensure that your application's dependencies are compatible with each other and with the Spring Boot version you are using.